# Syncing iPhone through VNC

Tags: iphone, vnc, realvnc

I have a situation where I would really like to sync my iPhone with my home PC (to add an audiobook for a long drive), however, I'm far from home and since this is Apple, I can't sync my iPhone with my laptop. I do, however, have a VNC server in my home PC, and I can access it (I'm using RealVNC Server/Viewer).

Is there a way to plug-in the iphone to my laptop and, using the VNC, "channel" it to my home PC and make it sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, VNC works for video and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do is use a third party to transfer files to your iPhone.  I'd suggest something like [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com) which you could use on your desktop via VNC to put the audio book online, and then use the DropBox iPhone client to download that same audio book onto your iPhone.

A 2GB DropBox account is free.